# Latex file not found with graphicspath

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I am using a script to generate and compile `.tex` files. But I have a problem with the `\graphicspath` command of `graphicx`. To add details, I am running on a Centos machine.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, c,  xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,ulem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\graphicspath{{../../1-data/results/beamer/PCA_byte7_bloc2_test/}}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=blue}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{ block 2 -  100 PCA vectors}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsectionhead}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{block2_100PCA_EigenVect}
\end{center}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{trace_block2_100PCA_EigenVect}
\end{center}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but I received

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `block2_100PCA_EigenVect.png' not found.
```

I triple checked the path and the file name and all seems correct. I also tried to put an absolute path in `\graphicspath` but it's still the same.

I mentioned the script part because the script is not executed in the folder with the `.tex` (and I can only access images in the script folder).

Comment: Have you tried with an image which does not have underscores in its name?

Comment: ...shouldn't be `\usepackage{graphicx}`? Not sure if it makes any difference, though.

Comment: I just tried and it makes no differences

Comment: Try, from the same directory from when you run pdflatex, to list it: `ls -l ../../1-data/results/beamer/PCA_byte7_bloc2_test/block2_100PCA_EigenVect.*`...

Comment: it was usepackage I used of course, I edited the question

Comment: @Rmano I can find the file using ls -l with my path from where  pdflatex is run

Comment: ... ok. Confused. Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Actually I do have this exact error, I don't where the .png is from (the file is .png though)

Comment: It can't know the file is png unless it finds it. the error message for the form where you do not give an extension is different one gives `! LaTeX Error: File \`zzz1' not found.` The other  `LaTeX Warning: File \`zzz2.png' not found on input line 15.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File \`zzz2.png' not found.`

Comment: on the newly supplied test document (if I don't have that file I get the error `! LaTeX Error: File \`block2_100PCA_EigenVect' not found.`

Comment: oh try removing `babel` (just as a test)

Comment: the .png part is strange, if I change the name to "dummy" `I got 
! LaTeX Error: File 'dummy' not found.` 
But when I put the correct filename (without .png) I still have my error :
`Package pdftex.def Error: File `block2_100PCA_EigenVect.png' not found.`

Comment: It works here for me... are you sure you do not have some strange symbolic link around? (I really I am not sure about what to think). Or same strange permission on the directory like having a `r` without an `x`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!